# @UniqueEntity custom message not translated

Tags: doctrine, symfony

How can I translate a message in a @UniqueEntity constraint?

I have this situation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="sites")
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"url"},
 *     message="This url is already registered. Please choose a different url."
 *     )
 */
class Site
{
```

If I leave the default message ("This value is already used.") it gets automatically translated with some bundled strings... but I can't find any documentation about how to translate the custom error messages. (I tried to put that string in the default domain, `messages`, but it doesn't get translated)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out.

The domain is **validators** and not **messages**, so you have to create a translation file in the `validators` domain, for example:

```
// app/Resources/translations/validators.it.php

return [
'This url is already registered. Please choose a different url.'=>'Questo url è già registrato. Scegli un url diverso.',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution.

First, set an identifier to your message:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="sites")
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"url"},
 *     message="entity.site.unique"
 *     )
 */
class Site
{
```

Then create any files ( messages.XX.yml ) as following, one per lang.

```
entity:
  site:
    unique: "Your message"
```

I hope this help.

Comment: mmm I use php files in the form of an array ex. "english"=>"italian"